# Sequential Model: TypeError: call() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)

Tags: nlp, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to create a multilayer bidirectional LSTM in Keras. Upon running the code below I get a TypeError raised initiating the forward model at `forward_model = keras.Sequential([fw_cell])`

It says the call() takes at least 3 arguments and that only two are given. I am not sure what this is referring to and therefore how to debug it. Is it saying I am not passing enough arguments to keras.Sequential()? or is it in reference to my StackedRNNCells/LSTMCell(s). Cheers!

```python
class Model_Keras():
def __init__(self, word_dim, sentence_length, class_size):
    rnn_size = 256
    num_layers = 2
    self.input_data = keras.Input(
        shape=[sentence_length, word_dim], dtype='float32')
    #self.output_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, sentence_length, class_size])

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------

    # Build independent forward stack of LSTM cells
    fw_cell = keras.layers.LSTMCell(rnn_size, dropout=0.5)

    # Stack the LSTM Cells
    fw_cell = keras.layers.StackedRNNCells([fw_cell] * num_layers, input_shape=(sentence_length, word_dim), name="fwd")

    # Instantiate model
    forward_model = keras.Sequential([fw_cell])

    # Build independent backward stack of cells
    # the same way as forward stack cells.
    bw_cell = keras.layers.LSTMCell(rnn_size, dropout=0.5)

    bw_cell = keras.layers.StackedRNNCells([bw_cell] * num_layers, input_shape=(sentence_length, word_dim))
    backward_model = keras.Sequential([bw_cell])

    # Outputs of forward and backward stacks are depth-concatenated

    merged_model = keras.layers.Concatenate(
        [forward_model, backward_model])

    # You can use TF functions to process the input
    # if using a TF backend for Keras
    processed_input = tf.unstack(tf.transpose(
        self.input_data, perm=[1, 0, 2]))

    # I don't think this is needed.
    # used = tf.sign(tf.reduce_max(tf.abs(self.input_data), reduction_indices=2))
    # self.length = tf.cast(tf.reduce_sum(used, reduction_indices=1), tf.int32)

    # Put together inputs and merged stacked LSTM models
    # apply bidirectional wrapper layer
    bidirectional = keras.Sequential(
        [processed_input,
         merged_model,
         keras.layers.Bidirectional()])

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    # Process bidirectional output
    model = keras.Sequential(
        [tf.transpose(tf.unstack(bidirectional), perm=[1, 0, 2])])
    model.add(keras.Reshape([-1, 2 * rnn_size]))

    # This step replaces weight_and_bias
    model.add(keras.Dense(class_size, input_dim=2 * rnn_size))
    model.add(keras.Activation('softmax'))
    model.add(keras.Reshape([-1, sentence_length, class_size]))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')

    return model
```

Full error message:

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model.py", line 97, in <module>
    epoch=10, lr=0.002, model_path="./trained_wordvec_model.pkl")
  File "model.py", line 87, in train
    model = Model_Keras(word_dim, sentence_length, class_size)
  File "model.py", line 32, in __init__
    forward_model = keras.Sequential([fw_cell])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 411, in __init__
    self.add(layer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 467, in add
    layer(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 619, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
TypeError: call() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Comment: Pls post your full error message. It's hard to say without details

Comment: Full error message added, thanks.